# How to ask Spacy phraseMatch to match all the token in the list?

Tags: python, nlp, matcher

I have a following algorithm:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
phrase_matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)


CAT = [nlp.make_doc(text) for text in ['pension', 'underwriter', 'health', 'client']]
                                
phrase_matcher.add("CATEGORY 1",None, *CAT)


text = 'The client works as a marine assistant underwriter. He has recently opted to stop paying into his pension. '
doc = nlp(text)
matches = phrase_matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
        rule_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # get the unicode ID, i.e. 'CategoryID'
        span = doc[start : end]  # get the matched slice of the doc
        print(rule_id, span.text)

# Output
CATEGORY 1 client
CATEGORY 1 underwriter
CATEGORY 1 pension
```

Can I ask to return the result when all words can be found in the sentence. I expect not to see anything here as 'health' is not part of the sentence.

Can I do this type of matching with PhraseMatcher? or Do I need to change for another type of rule based match? Thank you

Comment: Hm, good question. I don't think a rule would work here, because a rule is dependent on the order the words appear in the text AFAIK. You could simply check using a regular loop over the text like this: `l = ['pension', 'underwriter', 'health', 'client']; all_words_present = all(word in text for word in l)`

Comment: Actually, the more important thing is to identify rule_id if all words are present in the sentence, because I will add more patterns (nlp.make_doc).